# It appears that > behaves like >= in a soql query. Why?

Tags: soql, datetime

The query:

```
SELECT systemmodstamp, id 
FROM Lead 
WHERE SystemModstamp > 2013-12-03T01:13:09Z 
AND SystemModstamp < 2014-02-11T12:18:41Z 
ORDER BY SystemModstamp ASC ALL ROWS
```

returns several Lead SObjects with a SystemModstamp of: `2013-12-03T01:13:09Z`

Why? I would assume that the query above would include only Leads with a SystemModstamp of `2013-12-03T01:13:10Z` or greater.

**Update**:
I updated the string formatting of the SystemModstamp from the result set, and it looks like the records do not have ms values.
This apex:

```
//obj is a record returned from the query
//timestampField is a string with the value of 'SystemModstamp'
((DateTime)obj.get(timestampField)).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss:SSS\'Z\'')
```

rendered the following output:

```
2013-12-03T01:13:09:000Z
```

**Another Update:** Could this be caused by Timezones? Looks like the datetime objects I am using in my query are in PST.

**Another Update:**
'>' will never behave like '>='. It appeared to because a of timezone issue. When i work the bugs out of my code, I will post an answer.

My particular use case follows this flow:

- run a query retrieving all objects modified after a given date (by default 90 days in the past)
- store the largest SystemModstamp from the result set in a custom setting (as a DateTime)
- run another query retrieving all objects modified after the date stored in the custom setting
- update the custom setting with the largest SystemModstamp from the newest result set.

my query does not use a formatted datetime string, but instead uses variable binding.

**Last Update:** I don't know what was going on, but my code is working now. I have not solution, and can't reproduce the issue now. Is there a way to delete this question because I don't know what the solution is. The main point of this whole question has become Timezones. When you format a string it automatically converts the datetime to the timezone of the SF instance. (In my case PST). It could have been that in the process of debugging my code i switched from from bound datetime values in my soql query to string datetime values, and in so doing created the issue I was experiencing.

Comment: I wonder if those DateTimes are actually stored with `.000` millisecond precision?

Comment: what do you mean by that? and what would that effect?

Comment: 2013-12-03T01:13:09:001Z is greater than 2013-12-03T01:13:09:000Z, so if the .000 is stored and calculated, then it's possible you are confused because of a rounding issue...

Comment: All SOQL Datetime stamps are returned in UTC, if I recall correctly. Could this be your issue?

Comment: I think it is. When I use: 2013-12-03 09:13:09 the query excludes the results. anything less than that includes them. Since this appears to be a timezone issue, how should timezones be handled in a soql query?

Comment: Hello, edgar, can you remove the escaped quotes around the 'Z' in your format String? I think it will give you some more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create GMT DateTime objects you can try the following methods:

You can use raw numbers to create a `DateTime` object.

```
// Create your DateTime reference point using
// DateTime.newInstanceGmt(Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer)

DateTime referenceDate = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2013, 12, 3, 1, 13, 9);
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE SystemModstamp > :referenceDate];
```

Alternatively, you can use a String to create a `DateTime` object.

```
// Create your DateTime reference point using DateTime.valueOfGmt(String)

DateTime referenceDate = DateTime.parse('2013-12-03 01:13:09');
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE SystemModstamp > :referenceDate];
```

Comment: They might help, but I think the bigger problem is how I am retrieving, storing, and using datetime objects.